# Copy/paste with merged cells to keep format

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy a range from one sheet to another. On the source sheet, I have formatting and merged cells. I'd like an exact match on the target sheet. Source sheet is called `Budget Hours` and target sheet is called `Schedule`.

I tried

`Range("B5", Range("E1000")).Copy
Worksheets("Schedule").Cells(6, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Worksheets("Schedule").Cells(6, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`

It does the `PasteFormats` but gives an error for `PasteValues`. The error is **"Run-time error '1004'": You can't paste this here because the Copy area and paste area aren't the same size. Select just one cell in the paste area or an area that's the same size, and try pasting again."**

Then I tried `Sheets("Schedule").Range("B6:E500").Value = Sheets("Budget Hours").Range("B5:E499").Value`. This works but doesn't keep any of the formatting and undoes the merged cells.

An example of cells that are merged and formatted are `B5:D5`, with a blue background. I've attached a picture of what the source looks like.

[image]

How can I get an exact match on the target sheet (`Schedule`)?

Comment: One workaround is to paste everything first, then call `.Value = .Value` on the destination sheet.

Comment: @BigBen I was overthinking it. All I needed was `Range("B5", Range("E1000")).Copy Worksheets("Schedule").Cells(6, 2)`. Thanks for the help.